# No audio after XPProSP3 install to IBM/Lenovo T60 Thinkpad

Tags: windows-xp, thinkpad

Sound worked fine before installing XP Pro SP3......after install, no audio.

No audio after installing XP Pro SP3 on an IBM/Lenovo T60 ThinkPad.

IBM/Lenovo drivers from Lenovo Support site for "Audio Device on High Definition Audio Bus"

are not recognized when trying to install audio device.

Tried installing Microsoft drivers from Microsoft support site and got the same results.

Answer (score 2):

This is often a challenge.  Try the [ThinkVanatage System update](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=TVSU-UPDATE)  It will often find the missing component and address the issue.  Worked for same issue on my T61